# Use swift classes in Objective-c

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, clover-payment

I'm working with obj-C app, I need to integrate Clover Payment which are swift protocols. I have installed clover pods from
https://github.com/clover/remote-pay-ios

how to use swift protocols in obj-C? I have done this:

### In obj-C .h file

```
    @class ICloverConnector;
    @interface ViewPayment: UIViewController
    {
         ICloverConnector *cc;
    }
```

### In obj-C .m file

```
    #import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

### In ICloverConnector.swift

```
public protocol ICloverConnector : AnyObject {
    
     func addCloverConnectorListener(_ cloverConnectorListener:ICloverConnectorListener) -> Void
    
    
    func initializeConnection() -> Void
    
}
```

How do I call these two functions from Obj-C class ?

Comment: There are no Swift classes in your question. You've shown a Swift _protocol_. If you want to use that in Objective-C, mark it as `@objc`.

Comment: Adding @objc before that gets error :  Method cannot be marked "@objc" because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C.

Comment: You will need to create obj-c wrappers

Comment: @Cy-4AH Plz let me know how can we do it

Comment: @Sweeper Adding objc before it shows error as "Method cannot be marked as objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C

Comment: Also Exchange `AnyObject` with `NSObject`, which is not perfect but should work. Because it is more similar to objc's `id`. Or write the protocol in objc, then its more obvious that this pod is exposing the framework to objc but not the classes. If you like remind them to correct that with an issue in github

Comment: @Honey write special code with `@objc` markers

Comment: @Cy-4AH I have used wrappers , but it shows error : 
Method cannot be marked "@objc" because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C

Comment: No it isn't wrappers, you just added `@objc`. You need created type that wraps that type that can't be represented in objc and create method that wrapt method that can't be marked.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Can u plz share any link that shows what you are trying to explain

Comment: Honey you need a forward declaration @protocol MySwiftProtocol;
see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to use forward declarations.
See here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c